# Windows Service Fails To Start Through ManagedInstallerClass But Succeeds Through InstallUtil

Tags: c#, windows-services, installutil, managedinstallerclass

I have created a windows service in Visual studio 2012 (c#) that needs to be started after install. I have read so many articles and StackOverflow questions but none got it working. 
In the main function, I have:

```
static void Main(string []args)
{
     ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
}
```

I have registered AfterInstall event of the service.

```
private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
    {
        sc.Start();
    }
}
```

I'm logged in as an administrator. When I run the .exe file (as administrator), it tries to installs the service (keeps it in starting status for 2 minutes) but fails to start it. When I run in debug mode, I get an exception on sc.Start(). The log file says:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.
 The inner exception System.InvalidOperationException was thrown with the following error message: Cannot start service Database Convertor on computer '.'.
The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the following error message: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

I tried to change LocalService account to LocalSystem with no success.
Then I tried changing the main function too

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
             new Service1() 
        };
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

and when I installutil convertor.exe, it successfully installs and starts the service (but I need to start it through the program).

Why it starts the service when installing through installutil and why it throws an exception when I manually call installhelper?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing everything in the OnStart function in the service and see if it starts successfully, if it starts then debug the onStart function (You can user Debugger.Attach())

Best of luck

Comment: Not worked. Same issue:( I removed everything from onstart and onstop methods still..

Comment: Try to start your service OnCommitted not onAfterInstall

Comment: I tried it that way too. Plus i tried overriding the install function of installer.cs but both didn't worked out too.

Comment: If you remove service start (temporary) will the service be installed successfully? and after installing it can it be started successfully?

Comment: Yes. When it installs it successfully when i comment out servicecontroller.start() but when i try to start it from services.msc it fails and says: Service didn't respond in timely fashion. However when i install the service through installutil it starts automatically after the installation.

Comment: Check the user account used by the service after installation (without starting) and compare it with the user account when installing through installutil

Comment: How can i do that when installing through installutil?:(

Comment: You can check the user account from the services.msc, double click on the service and go to the "Log on" tab

Comment: Ok. In both the cases, its "Local Service". 
Same code, when installed though installutil works, but don't when installed through ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { ExePath });. There might be any problems with some sort of permissions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61294/discussion-between-ahmad-and-ali-baig).